# Grab and send a text value via a link using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to send the text typed in to a  box via a  link. Please see my code below. It isn't sending through for some reason?

```
<script>
    var discountCode = document.getElementById("discountCode").value;
        openPage = function() {
        location.href = "payment.php?discount="+discountCode;
    }                       
</script>
<a href ="javascript:openPage()" class="btn btn-warning">Purchase</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're reading the value as soon as the page loads, not when the link is clicked.  You just need to move the line into the function:

```
<script>
    openPage = function() {
        var discountCode = document.getElementById("discountCode").value;
        location.href = "payment.php?discount="+discountCode;
    }                       
</script>
<a href ="javascript:openPage()" class="btn btn-warning">Purchase</a>
```

Or alternatively just get a reference to the element when the page loads (assuming this script is *after* the `discountCode` element), then read the value in the function:

```
<script>
    var discountCode = document.getElementById("discountCode");
    openPage = function() {
        location.href = "payment.php?discount="+discountCode.value;
    }                       
</script>
<a href ="javascript:openPage()" class="btn btn-warning">Purchase</a>
```